# Local mdf file in Windows Application

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have added a local `.mdf` file (database file) to my Windows application which contains plenty of tables and stored procedures. Now the problem I am facing is that when I build my application, it takes 15 - 20 minutes for the build to complete. Can you help me to reduce the building time for my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach yor database in sql management studio/use static path and delete from the solution

Comment: I want to use this application in the client machine.The reason to add local .mdf file to my application is to access database values locally without connecting to the internet.Is there any way where we can avoid building the .mdf every time we build the solution ?

Comment: yes we can do this... simply put this mdf file in your project folder(don't attach it to the solution) and add connection in server explorer by using sqlExpress and get connection string from added connection...